# Delphi: Indy TIdTCPClient Reading XML

Tags: xml, delphi, indy

I'm opening a socket connection with TidTCPClient to a server.
Server starts sending me tones of different XML Data.
However ReadLn does not help me because I don't know where did the xml start & stops. So I decided to use Capture. This works correct. But as I read from the documentation capture also calling ReadLn, means it reads line by line. A 30~40 lines of XML takes 1~2 secs to read sometimes. So I need to read it faster. Can I use ReadStream or any other thing else which makes difference?

The code I'm using now:

```
procedure TfrmMain.ThreadRun(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
var
  FData: TStringList;
  FMemory: TStringStream;
begin
  if Client.Connected = False then Exit;
  FData := TStringList.Create;
  Client.IOHandler.Capture(FData, '', False);
  FMemory := TStringStream.Create('',TEncoding.UTF8);
  FMemory.WriteString(FData.Text);
  CoInitialize(Nil);
  QInsert.ParamByName('XMLData').LoadFromStream(FMemory,ftBlob);
  QInsert.Execute;
  CoUninitialize;
  FMemory.Free;
  FData.Free;
end;
```

As you can see I'm inserting XML data to a local table and this is done really quick, 15ms ~ 60ms depending on size of the XML, but getting data is really painful.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the TCP data you are trying to read?  Please show how multiple XML documents are being delimited (if at all) within the TCP stream.

Comment: BTW, on a side note, your `CoInitialize()` and `CoUninitialize()` calls belong in the `OnBeforeRun` and `OnAfterRun` events of `TIdThreadComponent`, not in the `OnRun` event.

Comment: Thanks for the CoInitialize() and CoUninitialize() warnings. I'd fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Capture()` calls `ReadLn()` in a loop until the specified terminator line is read (in your example, a blank line).

You need to know where each XML document ends and the next begins.  If there is no distinct marker in between each document (a blank line is fine, as long as every XML document ends with a line break before the blank line, and does not contain any blank lines inside of the XML), then your only remaining option is to read the first document's opening tag, keep reading until you find the corresponding closing tag, then read the next document's opening tag and wait for its closing tag, and so on.

In that case, you are best off using an XML parser that supports a push model to handle that.  You would simply read raw bytes from the socket and push them as-is into the parser, and let it tell you whenever it encounters the start and end of each top-level document element.  You can buffer any data the parser gives you in between those two events, using the start event to clear/prepare the buffer and the end event to finalize/flush the buffer to your database.

If you are not willing/able to use a pre-exising XML library, you will have to write your own parser.

**Update:** The example `Capture()` you showed has its `ADelim` parameter set to `''`, which will only work if the XML documents are delimited by either a `LF LF` or `CR LF CR LF` sequence.  In that case, you can use that delimiter as the `ATerminator` parameter of `ReadLn()` and let it read 1 whole document at a time, instead of using `Capture()` at all:

```
procedure TfrmMain.ThreadBeforeRun(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
begin
  CoInitialize(Nil);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.ThreadAfterRun(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
begin
  CoUninitialize;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.ThreadRun(Sender: TIdThreadComponent);
var
  Xml: String;
  FMemory: TStringStream;
begin
  // read until a 'CR LF CR LF' sequence is reached...
  Xml := TrimRight(Client.IOHandler.ReadLn(CR+LF+CR+LF, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8));
  // alternatively:
  // Xml := Client.IOHandler.WaitFor(CR+LF+CR+LF, True, False, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);

  FMemory := TStringStream.Create(Xml, TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    QInsert.ParamByName('XMLData').LoadFromStream(FMemory, ftBlob);
  finally
    FMemory.Free;
  end;

  QInsert.Execute;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Remy, Thanks for the answer. XML parser is MSSQL Server itself. No problems with the parser. Before finding Capture(), I'm doing the same thing with the ReadLn() by trying to find out closing tags. And thats where the problem begins. Some of the XMLs ends with just "/>" and some of them with "</closingtag>" also there are many "/>" closing tags inside big xml's inner trees so no way to find out where they really closed. And Capture() working perfect. As you said a blank line doing the job. How can I read raw bytes (ofcourse knowing where xml document finish) and push them to the table?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. If the TCP messaging does not provide delimiters between XML documents (and you have not shown what the actual TCP data looks like), then you need a **separate XML parser** to handle the streaming BEFORE you can put the individual XML document into the database. Precisely for the reasons you gave - the closing tags can be different, so it would be hard to tell Indy what to look for. You need to cache the inbound data into an intermediate buffer and parse that buffer for individual documents.The fact that MSSQL supports XML is *irrevelant* to this process.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example to replace `Capture()`.

Comment: This code did not work: `Xml := TrimRight(Client.IOHandler.ReadLn(CR+LF+CR+LF, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8));` But this works: `Xml := Client.IOHandler.WaitFor(CR+LF+CR+LF, True, False, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);` Also I make 2 different apps, one is working with Capture() and another one is working with WaitFor as you wrote. Both of them started at the same time and they got the exact same data: 2060 XML files during the test. So basically they're at the same speed for me. Now I can see may be this is the normal behaviour / normal speed of the  xml sending server. Nothing to do with my client.

Comment: `ReadLn(CR+LF+CR+LF)` and `WaitFor(CR+LF+CR+LF)` basically do the same thing internally - read from the socket until the `CR LF CR LF` arrives, and then return everything that was received before it. The difference is that `ReadLn()` will include the `CR LF CR LF` in its Result (thus the extra `TrimRight()`), whereas `WaitFor()` has an `AInclusive` parameter to strip it off upon exit. So I don't see how `WaitFor()` would work while `ReadLn()` does not, as they should be returning the same data each time (other than the difference mentioned above).

Comment: If you want me to dig into the `ReadLn()` issue further, you can post a new question about that (or email me privately), but please be sure to provide an example of the actual data that is being transmitted so I can run both methods through the debugger.